# How can I get LongListSelector SelectedItem as a string in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a longlistselector like the below image. now I wanna get the text of the item user's tapped. I've searched a lot but no solution found ;(
pay attention to the image please to give a sample code

http://amiryari.persiangig.com/image/stackoverflow-question.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Wire up the SelectionChanged event on the LongListSelector control:

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding MyListItems}"
                        SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
```

2) Retrieve the selected item from the AddedItems collection in the SelectionChangedEventArgs:

```
private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
     {
         var item = e.AddedItems[0];
     }
}
```

3) If your item is an object, and the text is displayed through a property, then you would have access to the text through the property on your object:

```
MyListItemObject item = e.AddedItems[0] as MyListItemObject;
MessageBox.Show(item.FullName);
```

If your list is bound to a list of strings, then it would simply be the first item in the AddedItems collection:

```
string fullName = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(fullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always listen for the `SelectionChanged` event and obtain the string. There is another way if you are using a DataTemplate to style your items in the list. Declare `Tapped` event in DataTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding ContactImage}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="NameTextBlock" Text="{Binding ContactName}" Tapped="NameTextBlock_Tapped"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate/>
```

Now in our code:

```
private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, BlahBlah e)
{
     var tb = sender as Textblock;
     string cName = tb.Text; //This is the string you wanted.
     MessageBox.Show(cName);
}
```